# SwiftUI and JSON file

Tags: swift

I have the following code, but am receiving an error message when running on the simulator:

```
        .fileImporter(
            isPresented: $isImporting,
            allowedContentTypes: [.json],
            allowsMultipleSelection: false
        ) { result in
            switch result {
                        case .failure(let error):
                            print("Error selecting file: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                        case .success(let urls):
                           for url in urls {
                               do {
                                   if url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() {
                                       url.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
                                        
                                       let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
                                       DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                           useridStore.userids = useridStore.parseJsonData(data: data)
                                           if useridStore.userids.count == 0 {
                                               print("nada")}
                                           else {
                                               print(String(useridStore.userids.count))

                                           }
                                       }
                                   }
               
                                   } catch let error {
                                   print("Error reading file \(error.localizedDescription)")
                               }
                           }
                       }
                   }
    }
```

The error message is as follows:

`typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil))`

Can anyone help?

Comment: This is one of the most common errors asked about here on stackoverflow when it comes to json decoding, did you try to google the error? You have an array in your file but you are trying to decode it as one object. If you still need help then please remove the irrelevant code you have posted and add the code relevant to the json decoding and a sample of your json

Comment: `func parseJsonData(data: Data) -> [UserID] {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    do {
    let useridStore = try decoder.decode(UserIDStore.self, from: data)
    self.userids = useridStore.userids
        
    } catch {
    print(error)
    }
    return userids
    }
}`

Comment: My JSON file has passed the test at [link]( https://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: What about decoding it as an array then, `decoder.decode([UserIDStore].self,…`

Comment: I replaced the two lines with ` userids = try decoder.decode(Array<UserID>.self, from: data)` and it worked.  Thanks do much for your help!